# SQL query to get values between multiple parentheses

Tags: sql

I need to get the values from withing a parentheses and sum them together. An example string is as follows

```
12233LT112(70) 12324AM331(80)
```

I want to sum the values in the parentheses, so in this example, it would sum to 150.

Is there any good way to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are these strings stored? How do they get there? What criteria will you need? How often will you need to run this query? Complex parsing problems like this are often symptoms of a data modelling problem.  It might be simpler to figure out how to store the data more efficiently.

Comment: How many of these type of sections will there be? Will the format be the same, xxxx(yy) etc too? where xxx is always x number of chars?

Comment: what database platform?  you can use regular expressions probably

Comment: Any answer is going to require the strings to be parsed or use tools such as xml or json, in all cases knowing your RDBMS is cruicial.

Comment: @n8wrl We import a .xlsx file to a temp table in MSSMS where we fix and update the info into the actual customer table. The quary will need to run about 2 times a month.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Each file contains about 100 - 500 rows with information. By the looks of it the pattern is, before my parentheses there is always 10 characters and my parentheses numbers can contain 2-3 characters.